# Error Wordpress jquery form error saying unreferenced function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building an emi caluclator in javascript to be used in a wordpress website. The problem is that i am getting the following error in the console.
**Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateEMI is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange** 
My code is as follows

HTML

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Outstanding Principle</th>
            <th>Interest Rate (%)</th>
            <th>Tenure </th>
            <th></th>
            <th>EMI</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="outstanding_principle" onchange="calculateEMI(this);">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="interest_rate" onchange="calculateEMI(this);">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="years" name="selection" value="years" onchange="calculateEMI(this);" /> Years
                <input type="radio" id="months" name="selection" value="Months" onchange="calculateEMI(this);" /> Months    
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tenure" onchange="calculateEMI(this);">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" readonly="true" id="emi">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My code for jquery is as follow kindly tell me where i am wrong.

```
<script>
        function calculateEMI(){
            var emi = 0;
            var P =0;
            var n = 1;
            var r = 0;

            if(jQuery("#outstanding_principle").val !== ""){
                P = parseFloat(jQuery("#outstanding_principle").val());
                if(jQuery("#interest_rate").val !== ""){
                    r = parseFloat(parseFloat(jQuery("#interest_rate").val()) / 100);
                }

                  if(jQuery("#tenure").val() !== ""){
                      n = parseFloat(parseFloat(jQuery("#tenure").val()));
                  }



            }
             if (P !== 0 && n !== 0 && r !== 0 && jQuery("#years").is(':checked')){
                 n = n * 12;
                 emi = parseFloat((P * r / 12) * [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n)] / [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n) - 1]);


            jQuery("#emi").val(emi.toFixed(2));
             }else if(P !== 0 && n !== 0 && r !== 0 && jQuery("#months").is(':checked')){
                  emi = parseFloat((P * r / 12) * [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n)] / [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n) - 1]);

                jQuery("#emi").val(emi.toFixed(2));
             }



        }
```

I am using a page builder. Also note that the console also shows me this at the top.
**JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1**

Comment: I'm not sure that passing `this` to your function is doing anything, as your function has no parameters. I could be mistaken, but I couldn't easily find any evidence otherwise.

Comment: When is the error thrown, on page load or after?

Comment: i removed this but still it shows the same error. The error comes after page is loaded and when i try to test it if it works. i put some loan values and other data in calculator and  it fails.

Comment: Where did you add the script? Looks like the function is not defined (or is not in the page at all). Do you see the code in the page source?

Comment: i tried to insert the script using a plugin called header and footer scripts. I added the jquery code in footer script. I think i would need to use the wp_enqueqe function to add the script. I will inform you all if i find the answer.

Comment: i tried again and this time it seems to work. I dont understand why the hell it didn't work at the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code working fine.

```js
function calculateEMI(){
            var emi = 0;
            var P =0;
            var n = 1;
            var r = 0;

            if(jQuery("#outstanding_principle").val !== ""){
                P = parseFloat(jQuery("#outstanding_principle").val());
                if(jQuery("#interest_rate").val !== ""){
                    r = parseFloat(parseFloat(jQuery("#interest_rate").val()) / 100);
                }

                  if(jQuery("#tenure").val() !== ""){
                      n = parseFloat(parseFloat(jQuery("#tenure").val()));
                  }



            }
             if (P !== 0 && n !== 0 && r !== 0 && jQuery("#years").is(':checked')){
                 n = n * 12;
                 emi = parseFloat((P * r / 12) * [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n)] / [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n) - 1]);


            jQuery("#emi").val(emi.toFixed(2));
             }else if(P !== 0 && n !== 0 && r !== 0 && jQuery("#months").is(':checked')){
                  emi = parseFloat((P * r / 12) * [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n)] / [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n) - 1]);

                jQuery("#emi").val(emi.toFixed(2));
             }



        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Outstanding Principle</th>
            <th>Interest Rate (%)</th>
            <th>Tenure </th>
            <th></th>
            <th>EMI</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="outstanding_principle" onchange="calculateEMI(this);">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="interest_rate" onchange="calculateEMI(this);">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="years" name="selection" value="years" onchange="calculateEMI(this);" /> Years
                <input type="radio" id="months" name="selection" value="Months" onchange="calculateEMI(this);" /> Months    
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tenure" onchange="calculateEMI(this);">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" readonly="true" id="emi">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: i know that it works fine but it does not work on wordpress website where i have added it.

Comment: you are calling calculateEMI() function before document ready?

Answer (score 0):

- There is noting wrong with code.
- **There may be error in some other code.**
- **Use developer toolbar to check error.**
- Use `calculateEMI();` instead of `calculateEMI(this);`

```js
function calculateEMI() {
    var emi = 0;
    var P = 0;
    var n = 1;
    var r = 0;

    if ($("#outstanding_principle").val !== "") {
        P = parseFloat($("#outstanding_principle").val());
        if ($("#interest_rate").val !== "") {
            r = parseFloat(parseFloat($("#interest_rate").val()) / 100);
        }

        if ($("#tenure").val() !== "") {
            n = parseFloat(parseFloat($("#tenure").val()));
        }
    }
    if (P !== 0 && n !== 0 && r !== 0 && $("#years").is(':checked')) {
        n = n * 12;
        emi = parseFloat((P * r / 12) * [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n)] / [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n) - 1]);


        $("#emi").val(emi.toFixed(2));
    } else if (P !== 0 && n !== 0 && r !== 0 && $("#months").is(':checked')) {
        emi = parseFloat((P * r / 12) * [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n)] / [Math.pow((1 + r / 12), n) - 1]);

        $("#emi").val(emi.toFixed(2));
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Outstanding Principle</th>
        <th>Interest Rate (%)</th>
        <th>Tenure Type</th>
        <th>Tenure</th>
        <th>EMI</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="outstanding_principle" onchange="calculateEMI();">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="interest_rate" onchange="calculateEMI();">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="years" name="selection" value="years" onchange="calculateEMI();" /> Years
            <input type="radio" id="months" name="selection" value="Months" onchange="calculateEMI();" /> Months
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="tenure" onchange="calculateEMI();">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" readonly="true" id="emi">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, initially I had same error as yours, but I noticed that you didn't close the **script** tag. I closed the **script** tag and tried the code the error disappeared.

Hope this helps you too.